# what is the systemd service file location best practise

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

New to systemd and unix and am unsure of the standards for the location of a systemd service file.

I want to follow the unix way and am wondering where a custom service file goes on ubuntu.

I have seen:

/usr/lib/systemd/user

/lib/systemd/system

/etc/systemd/system

What is the "best practice" location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/lib/systemd/system is the vendor shipped unit files and you can override them by placing them in /etc/systemd/system. There is a lot more about it. It is pretty lengthy but read the "Description" part on the following link: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html